# Flex Component Width

Tags: apache-flex, list, components, width

I have created an ItemRenderer for the Spark List component with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:RichText left="10" top="10" bottom="10" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0"
                paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0" text="{data[1].toString()}" textAlign="left"
                verticalAlign="middle" width="{parentDocument.width*0.96}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The problem is that when too much data is passed, the List controller displays scrollbars. Adding `right="10"` does not work. I need a way so that no scrollbars are present at any size (this is an AIR application).

Comment: Is the list displaying the scroll bar or is is the item renderer?  Is the scroll bar horizontal or vertical?  Your problem is not very clear.

Comment: I apologize, we are speaking about the vertical scroll bar. The list is displaying the scroll bar. Everything else is default.

Comment: Wait, what?!  A list is *suppose* to show scrollbars...  Without scrollbars, you can literally have thousands of rows which eats up memory.  What's the behavior you're trying to accomplish?  Also, have you tried DataGroup?

Comment: Sorry my big mistake, I meant the horizontal scrollbar, I wrote this late at night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the job.

```
        protected function ItemRenderer_Init(event:FlexEvent):void {
            setInterval(ResizeRenderer, 50);
        }

        private function ResizeRenderer():void {
            richtext.width = parentApplication.width-535;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **List** component consists of scroll bar itself. You can use **DataGroup** (same input parameter such as *itemRenderer=""* and *dataProvider=""* with **List**), and remember to set parameter *clipAndEnableScrolling="true"*.

This way also introduces new potential problem. When you have large amount of data, you cannot scroll up and down automatically. However, you can listen to mouseEvent to do it manually, or can add customized ScrollBar at anywhere in your application (set viewport="yourDataGroup").

Comment: Sorry my big mistake, I meant the horizontal scrollbar, I wrote this late at night.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about RichText (and scrollbars inside itemrenderer), setting `minHeight="0"` and `minWidth="0"` in RichText may solve the problem - the text will be cut. `variableRowHeight="true"` in List will make itemRenderers their own calculated size.

If you want List to always show all of its items, try to bind `rowCount` to your `dataProvider` length, say `rowCount="{Math.max(arrayOfDataToDisplay.length, 5)}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments for the op, it seems you have a problem with how you are laying out your item renderer.

1. Set the `percentWidth` of your item renderer to 100 (alternatively `width=100%`)
2. Set the `percentWidth` of your RichText to 100 (again, you can use `width=100%`)
3. Remove the `left`, `top` and `bottom` constraints.

Those two steps should get rid of your horizontal scroll bar problem.  If it continues you can try the nuclear option and set `horizontalScrollPolicy=off` on your `List`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, a horizontal scrollbar still appears (since some text may be very long). Turning off horizontalScrollPolicy is not an option, all the text needs to be displayed. In essence I'm trying to wrap the text, however this option is not available on newer versions of the flex framework.

Comment: Do you need to use RichText?  Can you use Label instead?  Label will automatically wrap text when percentWidth=100.  With RichText I think your text will need to have line breaks in order to wrap.

Comment: Unfortunately yes and line breaks for wrapping seem like a very bad idea, is there something in the label class I can copy to the RichText class to make it share the same behavior?

Comment: Since you have to use RichText I assume you are using [TextFlow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html).  You should look into [TextLayoutFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/formats/TextLayoutFormat.html) as it seems to be how you define formatting for TLF based components.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should consider setting the maxWidth property of your renderer to prevent it from getting bigger than your list.

Comment: Good point, and that almost solves the issue, the only problem now is when resizing, the scrollbar varies...